# change folder for all auxiliary files

Tags: xetex, texmaker, auxiliary-files

I'd like to know how I can save all the files created during compilation in a subfolder of the same name as the file. So I'd like to get:

`myfile.tex` 
`myfile.pdf` 
`myfile/` (containing *.aux, *.log, *.toc, etc pp)

Found a couple similar questions and understand that

a) (at least with `PdfLaTeX`) the commands `-output-directory=DIR`and `-aux-directory=DIR` change the target location for build and retrieval respectively.

b) where 'DIR' is '%', I get a folder of the name of the document.

So I tried using them in the Options for 'LaTeX' and 'XeLaTeX'. *Some of the files* were created in the `myfile/`-Folder, but it seems the program couldn't call them correctly for it didn't compile successfully.

*Q1: Is it the completely same commands with `XeLaTeX`?* 
*Q2: Where/How to implement this option in `Texmaker`? Is there's a possibility to change the target folder of **all auxiliary files** with typing the command **only once**?*

Using: 
`XeLaTeX` in `Texmaker 5.0.4` with `MiKTeX`

For the sake of completeness, these should be all the elements that generate auxiliary files I'm using at the moment in an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[ngerman,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{listings}
%% custom list of paragraphs
\makeatletter
    \newcommand\Paragraph[1]{%
        \addcontentsline{prg}{Paragraph}{#1}%
        \paragraph{#1}
    }
    \newcommand\l@Paragraph[2]{#1\dotfill \textit{#2}\\}
    \newcommand\listParagraphname{List of Paragraphs}
    \newcommand\listofParagraphs{%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\listParagraphname}
        \section*{\listParagraphname}\@starttoc{prg}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\clearpage

\section{Content}

A Listing: 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
    some code
\end{lstlisting} 
    
\Paragraph{A Paragraph} with some text... \\

\begin{tabular}{lr}
    col 1 & col 2 \\ \hline\\
    1 & 2 
\end{tabular}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        col 1 & col 2 \\ \hline\\
        1 & 2 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

%\clearpage

\section{Appendix}

\listofParagraphs 

\renewcommand{\lstlistlistings}{List of Listings}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings 

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\listfigurename} 

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\listtablename} 

\end{document}
```

PS: I would have provided a picture of my options screen, but didn't find the option to add an image. Comments on this are welcome as well.

PPS: I got it to create some files in the folder but apparently didn't read from there. (see Q1)

Comment: the normal advice is: don't do it. If you put the files in some non-standard place it is quite hard work to configure every other tool (like biber, makeindex etc) to find them.

Comment: I'd be ok with it only working on my PC for my personal convenience. On an other system it can just recreate all the files in the standard way. Also I got it to create some files in the folder but apparently didn't read from there.

Comment: Well then spent a few hours to get it working. You can find a lot questions about various aspects of this on the internet. I think that it is not worth the time and certainly not my worth my time. See also https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/46#note_406225858

Comment: Thanks for the provided link! I find the thread to be quite helpful in understanding the matter more deeply. Also your specification there about all involved tools needing to be adressed seperately - as I would have supposed LaTeX may provide a certain degree of centralisation and freedom there. I'll further tackle the issue once I've got a couple hours at hand.